# Rewrite url with htaccess before frontcontroller sees it without redirect

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I need to rewrite links of `api/mobile/3/*` to `api/mobile/v3/*` due to a restriction of our router, we're modernizing an existing codebase (paths can't start with numbers because they map to php namespaces)

The following works if I add an R flag to the api rewrite - as in it redirects me to the proper place.

I ***can't*** have a redirect though as the existing apps that use this API **will not follow a redirect**.

```
# make sure mod_rewrite is ON
    RewriteEngine On

# rewrite api 3 to v3
    RewriteRule ^api/mobile/3/(.*) api/mobile/v3/$1 [QSA]

# send other requests to the application
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule .* /index.php [QSA,L]
```

When I remove the front controller call, Apache gives me a 404 to the **correct** v3 path I want, so the problem I suspect is somewhere in the combination of the first RewriteRule and the second.

I'm realizing while writing this that this is probably because rewrite just changes what file gets executed and not the SERVER variables.

Is there any way to get apache to rewrite what gets handed off to the front controller to make this work?

Comment: It does not, its a path I need the front controller to handle. The problem is the front controller is still given /3/ instead of /v3/ as the `REQUEST_URI`.  I suspect RewriteRules don't change the `REQUEST_URI` and am not sure how to solve that.

Comment: @donatJ mod_rewrite changes the `%{REQUEST_URI}` apache variable, but not the php handler's `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` variable. To change that, you're probably need to internally proxy the request. Do you have mod_proxy loaded?

Comment: @JonLin a simple changing of [QSA] to [QSA,P] uses mod_proxy and makes it work! Thank you!.  If you answer the question below I'll accept it!